# Nesting ui-gmap-markers directives

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

Is it possible to nest `ui-gmap-markers` directives (the plural version of `ui-gmap-marker`)?

For example, I have the following data structure:

```
vm.states = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'California',
        location: {
            latitude: 36,
            longitude: -119
        },
        cities: [{
        id: 1,
            name: 'Los Angeles',
            location: {
                latitude: 33.75,
                longitude: -118
            }
        }, {
        id: 2,
            name: 'San Francisco',
            location: {
                latitude: 38,
                longitude: -123
            }
        }, {
        id: 3,
            name: 'San Diego',
            location: {
                latitude: 32.5,
                longitude: -117
            }
        }]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Nevada',
        location: {
            latitude: 39,
            longitude: -117
        },
        cities: [{
        id: 4,
            name: 'Las Vegas',
            location: {
                latitude: 36,
                longitude: -115
            }
        }, {
        id: 5,
            name: 'Reno',
            location: {
                latitude: 39,
                longitude: -119
            }
        }]
    }];
```

I would like to display the cities associated with each state, so I would like to have:

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="vm.states">
     <ui-gmap-markers>
```

If I can, then what would I use for the "models" attribute in the nested directive?

I have been able to do this using `ng-repeat` with `ui-gmap-marker`. However, I am having some performance issues, so I would like to use the plural version of the directive.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9eubhLq/2/)** of version using ng-repeat with the singular version of the directive (`ui-gmap-marker`)

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6trhpdt/1/)** of version using the plural version of the directive (`ui-gmap-markers`). Notice the nested `ui-gmap-markers` that I would like to use for the cities. I just don't know how to access the model from the parent.

Comment: i think you can accomplish by doing `<ui-gmap-markers ng-repeat="state in states">
     <ui-gmap-markers>`

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle for the singular version of the directive and the plural version of the directive that I need help with

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta correct me if I'm wrong, you want to render only inner ui-marker through directive? & could you explain us what are the performance issue you are getting?

Comment: I would like to display the state and their corresponding city markers just like in the first JSFiddle. The reason I want to use the `ui-gmap-markers` instead of `ng-repeat` with `ui-gmap-marker` is that the markers are taking a while to display. The JSFiddle examples are a very scaled down version of my code. In reality, my model contains a lot more data.

Comment: I wouldn't mess with that directive. The `ng-repeat` is probably the right way to go, just try some bindonce or `limitTo` to only load a subset at a time and more per batches, or maybe as the user zooms.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta I was using ui-gmap-markers with ng-repeat but when I was using any kind of filtering unforntunally the perfomance was really low, sometimes my browser stop working, so I decided to make my own directive

Answer (score 3):

I managed to display cities using lodash (the dependency was already set in the jsfiddle).

Here the
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9eubhLq/4/)

Here is the coding:

```
    vm.cities = _.reduceRight(vm.states, function(listCities, other) {
  return listCities.concat(other.cities);
}, []);
```

You can imagine put this code in a `$watch()` or `watchCollection()`

I hope it help you

Answer (score 2):

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kozlice/x1dfa74n/3/

```
$scope.data = [ /* ... */ ];

$scope.statesList = [];
$scope.citiesList = [];

$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.statesList.length = 0;
    $scope.citiesList.length = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (state) {
        $scope.statesList.push(state);
        if (!angular.isArray(state.cities)) {
            return;
        }
        angular.forEach(state.cities, function (city) {
            $scope.citiesList.push(city);
        });
    });
}, true);
```

Any changes to data (as you most likely fetch it from server API) will trigger markers update.

PS. It's scope's responsibility to store data, controller must not be used for this purpose. Implicit DI annotation should also be avoided (in favor of inline array / $inject).